# How to access array if I get the name of the array from a selected option?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a list of items:

```
<select id ="listSelector">
        <option value="books">Books</option>
        <option value="countries">Countries</option>
        <option value="states">States</option>
        <option value="presidents">Presidents</option>
</select>
```

Which correspond to arrays of items:

```
var books = ['genesis', 'exodus', 'leviticus', 'numbers'];
var countries = ['Akrotiri','Albania','Algeria','American'];
var states = ['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas'];
var presidents = ['Washington','Adams','Jefferson','Madison'];
```

I want to be able to select an item from the list and use the value of the item to select the correct array.

```
var listSelector = document.getElementById('listSelector');
var selectedList = listSelector.options[listSelector.selectedIndex].value;
console.log('selected', selectedList[0]); 
// returns first letter of the value of the list that was selected
// instead of the first item in the array.
// Ex. If I selected the Books option, the value would be 'books' 
// and I want to access the books array.
```

Comment: Use an object instead of separate variables `var infos = { "books": [...], "countries": [...], ... }; infos[selectedValue]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change the structure to an object instead, it would be quite easy

```js
var stuff = {
  books      : ['genesis', 'exodus', 'leviticus', 'numbers'],
  countries  : ['Akrotiri', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'American'],
  states     : ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas'],
  presidents : ['Washington', 'Adams', 'Jefferson', 'Madison']
}

var listSelector = document.getElementById('listSelector');

listSelector.addEventListener('change', function() {

  var item_array = stuff[listSelector.value];
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(item_array, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
  
}, false);
```

```html
<select id="listSelector">
  <option value="books">Books</option>
  <option value="countries">Countries</option>
  <option value="states">States</option>
  <option value="presidents">Presidents</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do `console.log('selected',selectedList)` you will notice that it is the string value for the selected option. So doing `selectedList[0]` when the selected item is "book" will return "b" since using array index notation on strings returns the character for the given index.

Right now your lists (books,contries,states,presidents) are all stored on the global object. For browsers this is defined as `window`. So you can access any of your declared variables with.

```
window.book
```

But we can also use Strings to access properties like this

```
window['books']
```

So when we get the string representation for the variable name that we want we can access it like so

```
window[selectedList]
```

This will give us the target array and we can then access properties on it.

```
window[selectedList][0]
```

So if "book" was selected the above code would return "genesis". To get your original intended value of selected list we can break this process into two steps by creating an intermediate variable to store the name of the target list

```
var selectedListName = listSelector.options[listSelector.selectedIndex].value;
var selectedList = window[selectedListName]
console.log('selected', selectedList);
```

We can go one step further and create our own object to store all the lists instead of using the global `window` object.

```js
var lists = {
  books : ['genesis', 'exodus', 'leviticus', 'numbers'],
  countries : ['Akrotiri', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'American'],
  states : ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas'],
  presidents : ['Washington', 'Adams', 'Jefferson', 'Madison']
}

var listSelector = document.getElementById('listSelector');
var selectedListName = listSelector.options[listSelector.selectedIndex].value;
var selectedList = lists[selectedListName]
console.log('selected', selectedList);
```

```html
<select id="listSelector">
  <option value="books">Books</option>
  <option value="countries">Countries</option>
  <option value="states">States</option>
  <option value="presidents">Presidents</option>
</select>
```